# how to extract array from java to ajax

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, arrays

I get the values  from database to **time** array as follow

```
int[] time=Manager.playTime() ;               
responsedata.put("status", "success");
responsedata.put("play", time);
```

And i am sending this **time** array to ajax in javascript file as follow

```
 success:function(response){
     $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
     if(response.status == 'success'){
        for( var i=0;i<response.play.length;i++){
           alert("playtime---"+response.play[i]);
     }
```

but here i am not getting the values from array .Please help me

Thanks

Comment: can you post the `console.log(response)`

Comment: you can't access object directly. You need to access the object via keys representing object data.

Comment: by using console.log(response) i get [object Object]

Comment: In your console you are getting whole object i.e. response>

Answer (score 0):

You `responsedata` seems to be a Java Map.

Try to use this in your success function

```
success:function(response){
     $('body').css('cursor', 'default');
     if(response.status == 'success'){
        $.each(response.play, function (value) {
             alert("playtime---"+value);
        });
     }
}
```

Comment: please tell me how to use in my code i.e. above code

Answer (score 0):

In your ajax you are getting whole object in response i.e. response.
You can get your play object by response i.e. `response.play`.
now iterate the the values from play object.

```
for (var i = 0; i < response.play.length; i++) {
   //iterate your values here
    alert(response.play[i].object_key);
   //object_key is temparary name of your play object so give a proper key here.
}
```